# Accessing RubyOnRails variable in Javascript says variable is undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created an instance variable in my RubyOnRails controller (index.rb) named `@var_ror`

In my javascript file (fetchingDataFromRoR.js.erb) I try to access this RubyOnRails variable and assign it to a javascript variable.

```
var var_js = '<%= @var_ror %>'
```

I get an error saying `@var_ror` is undefined.

However, if I use a global variable named `$var_ror` and access it in javascript like this:

```
var var_js = '<%= $var_ror %>'
```

It works. However, I don't want a variable of global scope and also it causes other problems.

Comment: Can we see your controller method?

Comment: what about var var_js = '<%= @var_ror %>'.

Comment: Also, look into [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon)

Comment: You'll be best posting your controller action

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

**controller:**

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render "fetchingDataFromRoR", :locals => {:var_ror => @var_ror} }
end
```

**fetchingDataFromRoR.js.erb:**

```
var var_js = <%= var_ror %>;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing js and ruby incorrectly. the correct syntax is

```
var var_js = '<%= @var_ror %>'
```

**reason:**

let `@var_ror = "some_string"`

then your

`var var_js = <%= @var_ror %>` 
resulting in  `var var_js = some_string` , now some_string looks like a variable which not defind and so, will throw an error

Comment: I had the quotes in place. It was a typo for me to miss those in the question. I face the problem even with the quotes.